# Scaling down images with css to fit in a container

Tags: css

So I want to scale an image down with css into the size of a container, while maintaining its aspect ratio. It seems easy enough to achieve this when specifying the minimum height OR width, but not both. Any ideas?

Comment: So...why can't you use just width, or height?

Comment: @David: If he just chooses, e.g., width, then when he has a very *tall* image, it will break the height constraint of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out if the height is less or the width is less; whichever dimension is less, set that property of the `img` but not the other. Assuming you aren't setting the size of the `img` in CSS, this should maintain the aspect ratio while making the image as large as possible within the constraints of the container. This code assumes your container is a `div`.

```
var height = $('#divImg').Height();
var width = $('#divImg').Width();

if (height > width)
{
    $('#divImg img').Width(width);
}
else
{
    $('#divImg img').Height(height);
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you aren't using jQuery, you can use the following CSS trick to maintain aspect ratio. Change `100px` to the size of your container:

```
#divImg img {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}  
#divImg img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Borrowed from [CSS styling image height and width while maintaining aspect ratio](http://addedoptimization.com/css-styling-image-height-and-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio/).

Comment: This also assumes he's using [tag:jquery]. And, therefore, [tag:javascript]. Although I realise that JavaScript's necessary for this...

Comment: @David, I updated my example to include a CSS-only method, though it presupposes he knows the size of his container.